# Como obtener todos los productos que no tengan ventas los ultimos X meses que tengan 0 de stock en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Que me recomendarían para crear una **Query** que cumpla con esta condición en MYSQL, llevo horas y no me da la cabeza, seguro que es simple y no le llego..

Tengo 2 tablas, tb.productos y tb.detalleVenta

Basada en la la cantidad de stock de la tb.productos, necesito que todo producto que tenga stock de 0 y tenga mas de 3 meses sin registrar ventas deshabilitarlo

En la tb.detalleVenta ademas del id del producto lleva una fecha en la que se registro la venta del producto como detalle

Como harían ustedes para conseguir lo que indico..

hasta el momento no paso de este simple Join

SELECT p.idproducto,p.descripcion, p.stock, d.fecha FROM productos AS p INNER JOIN detalleVenta AS d ON d.idproducto = p.idproducto WHERE p.stock =0

Les agradecería sus consejos.

Comment: y te falta una condicion para la fecha... donde tenes la ultima fecha de venta del producto?

Comment: lo unico que tiene fecha de venta es la de detalleventa , pero en la tabla puede haber varias ventas del mismo producto, la idea seria como tomar la ultima venta que se haya registrado de dicho producto y verificar si tiene mas de 3 meses respecto al dia de la consulta

Comment: y como obtenes la ultima venta de un producto?

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias por la intención, ya conseguí la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

**Basicamente, con una sub query despues del WHERE seleccione por el ID de producto el que tuviera la fecha Maxima y con el resultado comparo  con la fecha Actual menos 3 meses para lograr saber que producto no tienen ventas los ultimos 3 meses, y con el DISTINCT evito los duplicados**

```
   SELECT DISTINCT p.idproducto,p.descripcion, p.stock
    FROM productos AS p 
    INNER JOIN detalleVenta AS d 
    ON d.idproducto = p.idproducto 
    WHERE p.stock = 0 
    AND (DATE((SELECT MAX(f.fecha) AS maxDate FROM detalleVenta AS f WHERE f.idproducto = 
    p.idproducto)) < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
```

Comment: Por favor, explica la respuesta.. una respuesta que es solo codigo solo la entendes vos...